# Where clause to return all values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run below sql query and hoping to return two values. Unfortunately, it only return the first one. Can anyone assist?

```
SELECT *
FROM SUPPLIER
where
(CITY IN ('BERLIN') AND SUPPLIER IN ('CompanyA')) OR 
(CITY IN ('SYDNEY') AND SUPPLIER IN ('CompanyB'))
```

It's only returning the first line (Berlin/Company A) without Sydney/Company B

Comment: Your query seems ok to me. Can you post some sample data reproducing the issue?

Comment: It can be improved but yes would work